# ExtJS 6 What package should I require for Ext.ux.colorpick.Field to work?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I want to use [Ext.ux.colorpick.Field](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.ux.colorpick.Field.html) (modern toolkit), but can not figure out what should I require for it to work.

I've tried `ext-ux-colorpick` package within app.json, but it leads to an error:

*Failed to resolve dependency Ext.form.field.Picker for file Ext.ux.colorpick.Field.*

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to:

1 - Install package with `npm install @sencha/ext-ux` (not globally).

2 - Change packages path in the `workspace.json` to `${workspace.dir}/node_modules/@sencha`:

```
  "packages": {
    "dir": "${workspace.dir}/node_modules/@sencha",
    "extract": "${workspace.dir}/node_modules/@sencha/remote"
  }
```

3 - Add `ux` to the `requires` in the `app.json`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `ux` widgets you need to require it in `app.json` like:

```
  "requires": [
    "ux"
  ],
```

And in `app.js` or in some `Ext.app.Controller` add in `requires`.

```
requires: ['Ext.ux.colorpick.Field']
```

Comment: Stacked with error `Cannot satisfy requirements for "ux"!` when building my app.